# NHibernate delete from LINQ results

Tags: linq, nhibernate

I'm wondering about the best usage of the delete method in nhibernate.

If you go the entity than just call delete and send it, but if not you need to query it or write a query and send it to delete method.

I'm wondering if its possible to write a linq expression and send it to delete.

Is it possible to perform a Linq transformation to hql and than call session.Delete(query)
with the generated hql?

I want to call Session.Delete, and give it a linq so it can know what to delete without selecting the data. Do you know a class that can convert linq expression to hql?

Comment: You can use query for session.Delete

    <li>session.Delete(string query) (It will delete all objects returned by the query</li>

Comment: I really believe this is something that should be added to NHibernate.Linq. Maybe an extension method in ISession that adds a Delete method accepting a Linq expression. The LINQ provider in NHibernate, if my memory doesn't fail me converts it to NHibernate criteria, so it may be possible to do that. It would be great to be able to delete without 2 trips to the server and without having to resort to HQL again. Something like this: session.Delete(session.Query<Employee>(e => e.Name == "Loudenvier")) and have it transformed in DELETE statement!

Comment: I believe I really messed up things in my previous comment... for the sake of brainstorming I'll let it there... but I think that the best solution is maybe similar to the Fetch(), FetchMany() approach... Just adding a Delete() would probably do... Keep in mind I'm no expert in NHibernate nor Linq, just a noobie on this subject with wild speculative ideas :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Q in LINQ stands for "Query". So, no, you can't use a LINQ expression for delete.

That said, NH's query language, HQL, *does* support that.

In the same way that you can say "from Foo where Bar = :something" to get all the foos matching a condition, you can do this:

```
session.CreateQuery("delete Foo where Bar = :something")
       .SetParameter("something", ...)
       .ExecuteUpdate();
```

Comment: @Chen I did understand it. But what you want to do is not possible. You can't do that with LINQ, use HQL.

Comment: @Diego Sorry to bring up an old discussion, but I disagree. Yes LINQ is a type of query (a language integrated one), but there is nothing wrong with a query that returns results to be deleted. A SQL delete statement is the same thing, a query that returns results to be deleted, rather than returned to the client. The ISession would have 2 extension methods, one called Query<> that returns the linq results, and one called Delete<>. The Delete<> would use a different IQueryProvider that performs the same expression tree analysis but instead puts it into a delete statement.

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon 'The Q in LINQ stands for "Query". So, no, you can't use a LINQ expression for delete.'
-- The first sentence is just mystification, what stands the 'Q' in the HQL or in the SQL for? :)

Answer (score 5):

You now can directly in linq with NHibernate 5.0

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Delete all entities selected by the specified query. The delete operation is
    //     performed in the database without reading the entities out of it.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   source:
    //     The query matching the entities to delete.
    //
    // Type parameters:
    //   TSource:
    //     The type of the elements of source.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The number of deleted entities.
    public static int Delete<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source);
```

Exemple:

```
        var tooOldDate = System.DateTime.Now.AddYears(5);
        session.Query<User>()
            .Where(u => u.LastConnection <= tooOldDate)
            .Delete();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have submitted a pull request for NH-3659 - Strongly Typed Delete. The link is available at nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3659.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but for those reading this now. NHibernate 5 released Oct 10, 2017 has added a Delete Linq extension

from documentation [17.6.3. Deleting entities](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querylinq.html)
Delete method extension expects a queryable defining the entities to delete. It immediately deletes them.

```
session.Query<Cat>()
    .Where(c => c.BodyWeight > 20)
    .Delete();
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure it would be possible to do what you want but the bottom line is that it doesn't make a lot of sense (not sure why you want to give NHibernate the select criteria when you can do it in a single statement, your approach would end up causing 2 hits to the database), having said that, one easy option you could do, is query the IDs using LINQ and pass those to NHibernate

```
int[] deleteIds = (from c in Customer where {some condition} select c.Id).ToArray<int>();

session.CreateQuery("delete Customer c where c.id in (:deleteIds)")
            .SetParameterList("deleteIds", deleteIds)
            .ExecuteUpdate();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to avoid the 2 round trips to db.